# Using Netbeans on solo project, new to Git/GitHub, do I need an account?

Tags: git, netbeans, github, version-control

If I'm just a solo dev working on a personal project but still want to use Git for local versioning, do I need a Github account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just care about version control on your local machine, then you **do not** need a GitHub account.

If you ever want to work on multiple machines, then you will need a place to host your remote repository. GitHub is the most popular option, but there are other online providers like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) or [GitLab](http://gitlab.com).

If you want all the fancy features of an online repository host like Github, but you don't want your code on someone else's servers, then you could host your own remote repository using something like GitLab CE, which is a free version of GitLab's local Git hosting solution.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is a repository for code hosting, if you need only local versioning as @BrokenBinary says you don't need a GitHub account, just download Git on your local machine from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads), move to your project directory and initialize your local git repository with the command `git init`